# Ignore trailing commas mid file, ignore trailing incomplete rows

Tags: python, excel, csv, parsing

I am dealing with CSV files which have been tampered with by others in Excel and thus somehow contain additional commas (seperators) mid file and incomplete rows at the end of the file.

Naturally Pandas/Python's CSV reader can't handle such files.

I was wondering if someone knows of an already existing solution for working around such annoying features. I appreciate non-trivial advice on writing a solution from scratch.

To illustrate :

```
CSV file contents:

header1, header2
1,1
2,3
5,8,,
1
1
```

Comment: What's the content should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def preprocess(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:    
        for line in csvfile.readlines[1:]:
            if ',' in line:
                yield list(map(int, line.split(',')[0:2]))
```